# On how to run custom keras code on TPU cloud

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have my code written to run on GPU, but the turnaround time for experiments is a lot.I want to port this code so i can run it on TPU. how i can do so? This i what i have.

```
Bunch of datloading stuff
!!!!!
!!!!!

effnet = efn.EfficientNetB5(weights=None, include_top=False)
effnet.load_weights(eff_weights_path)

# Replace all Batch Normalization layers by Group Normalization layers

model = Sequential()
model.add(effnet)
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(8,name ='elu', activation=elu))
model.load_weights('saved_models/wieghts_ef5.h5',by_name = True)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse', 'acc'])
print(model.summary())        

model_json = model.to_json()
with open("./saved_models/model_ef5_fn.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

BATCH_SIZE = 2
IMG_WIDTH  = 456
IMG_HEIGHT = 456
# Add Image augmentation to our generator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=360,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   vertical_flip=True,
                                   validation_split=0.15,
                                   preprocessing_function=preprocess_image, 
                                   rescale=1 / 128.)

# Use the dataframe to define train and validation generators
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(df, 
                                                    x_col='pic_id', 
                                                    y_col=Labels_list,
                                                    directory = train_images_path,
                                                    target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
                                                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                    class_mode='other', 
                                                    subset='training')

val_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(df, 
                                                  x_col='pic_id', 
                                                  y_col=Labels_list,
                                                  directory = train_images_path,
                                                  target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
                                                  batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                  class_mode='other',
                                                  subset='validation')
print('Data was loaded')


# For tracking Quadratic Weighted Kappa score
kappa_metrics = Metrics()
# Monitor MSE to avoid overfitting and save best model
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='auto', verbose=1, patience=15)
rlr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', 
                        factor=0.5, 
                        patience=4, 
                        verbose=1, 
                        mode='auto', 
                        min_delta=0.0001)

# Begin training
model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    # steps_per_epoch=60,
                    steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // BATCH_SIZE,                    
                    epochs=30,
                    validation_data=val_generator,
                    # validation_steps = 30,
                    validation_steps = val_generator.samples // BATCH_SIZE,                    
                    callbacks=[kappa_metrics, es, rlr])
```

Comment: where did `GroupNormalization` layers come from? What about `efn`?

Comment: @InnocentBystander its from package `import efficientnet.keras as efn`

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'efficientnet' has no attribute 'GroupNormalization'.` Maybe at least add an import block at the top of your example, so people don't have to guess where things came from.

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'efficientnet.keras'`

Comment: @InnocentBystander Hey really sorry about that, let me add.

Comment: @InnocentBystander I have added it now, are you trying to run this code? Should we take this to chat? even i can run it in parallel and check

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of code... For the sake of making a minimal reproducible example, maybe temporarily replace all the custom layers with keras equivalents.

Comment: @InnocentBystander Yes , that should should be fine, just remove the Radam optimizer and set it to 'adam' and may be you can do away with efficientNet  and just run it with resnet.

Comment: I have made the edits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198959/discussion-between-ryan-and-innocent-bystander).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in chat here is the basic design to train your model on a TPU:

```py
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import *

!pip install -U git+https://github.com/qubvel/efficientnet
import efficientnet.tfkeras as efn

backend.clear_session()

if "COLAB_TPU_ADDR" not in os.environ:
    raise Exception("TPU not found")

tpu_addr = "grpc://" + os.environ["COLAB_TPU_ADDR"]
print("TPU address:", tpu_addr)

resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu = tpu_addr)
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_host(resolver.master())
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)

def get_model():
  effnet = efn.EfficientNetB5(weights = None, include_top = False)

  # Replace all Batch Normalization layers by Group Normalization layers
  for i, layer in enumerate(effnet.layers):
      if "batch_normalization" in layer.name:
          effnet.layers[i] = GroupNormalization(groups = 32, axis = -1, epsilon = 1e-5)

  model = models.Sequential()
  model.add(effnet)
  # add other layers
  return model

with strategy.scope():
  model = get_model()
  model.compile(optimizer = optimizers.Adagrad(learning_rate = 0.1), 
    loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics = ["sparse_categorical_crossentropy"]
  )

  #model.load_weights("/path/to/imagenet/weights")

print(model.summary())

# model.fit(...)
model.save_weights("weights.h5")

cpu_model = get_model()
cpu_model.load_weights("weights.h5")
#cpu_model.predict(...)
```